# When you talk about an experience at some place, do you use past tense?

Tags: grammar

When I talk about a meal which I had at a restaurant, and given that the restaurant still exists; Should I use the past tense or the present tense? For example:

> I had a meal called "chicken roller" for the first time at a
>   restaurant called "Bashkeer".  The restaurant **was** spacious and the
>   lighting **was** fabulous, and the waiters went the extra mile to make us comfortable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you *ate* the meal previously, i.e., in the *past*, use the past tense, as you wrote. What difference does it make whether or not the restaurant still exists?

That said, if I were reviewing a restaurant, and I want to state that it is currently a good place to eat, then it might look like this:

`Try the "chicken roller" at the Bashkeer Restaurant. The restaurant is spacious, the lighting is fabulous, and the waiters go the extra mile to make the diner comfortable.`

Here, the present tense makes sense.